# WSO2 ESB with BRS and Data Services Features

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I've been testing WSO2 BRS and WSO2 Data Services separately and working properly. The next step was to add in the WSO2 ESB the features that provide these capabilities, but they have bugs that keep the deployment of services.

BRS Feature: Can't upload the . jar with the class model for rules. (Rule Service - 3.2.0)

Data Services Feature: Various failures to create new services, not looking tables of datasource and can't upload the services created previously. (Data Service Hosting - 3.2.0)

Has anyone done these features work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the ESB version you are using? If it is ESB 4.0.3, please install the latest versions of Rule Service and Data Services features. 
Rule Service and Data Services versions: 3.2.2

Thanks

Thilini